# como criar um alias no Git para o comando "log --pretty=oneline"

Tags: git

Como diz o título, eu preciso criar um alias para o comando "log pretty=oneline".

Eu sei da existência da sintaxe avançada do bash para fazer isso, mas não posso aprender isso no momento, por enquanto só gostaria do código para fazer isso...

Comment: Acho que isso deve ajudar, ter uma lista de alias e muito bom! https://gist.github.com/kelvinst/331aff32508e2517afbd

Comment: ajudou assim, e de quebra aprendi como fazer com outros comandos. valeu!